# `vim.eval('a:items')` fails if 'a:items' contain `BOM HEADERs`

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-python

I am using a pluging `ctrlp-py-matcher`, which is using the python interface to
vim. My VIM is compiled with `python3` support

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 17, compiled Jul  1 2018 10:45:10) Included
patches: 1-42 Compiled by username@username-VirtualBox Huge version with GTK2
GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-): +acl               +farsi
+mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white +arabic            +file_in_path
-mouse_sysmouse    -tcl +autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt
+termguicolors -autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm
+terminal +balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse +browse
+fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects ++builtin_terms    +gettext
+netbeans_intg     +timers +byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64
+title +channel           +iconv             +packages          +toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
+clientserver      +job               +perl              +vertsplit +clipboard
+jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit +cmdline_compl     +keymap
+postscript        +visual +cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer
+visualextra +cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +viminfo
+comments          +libcall           -python            +vreplace +conceal
+linebreak         +python3           +wildignore +cryptv
+lispindent        +quickfix          +wildmenu +cscope            +listcmds
+reltime           +windows +cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft
+writebackup +cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +X11
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        -xfontset +diff
+mksession         +signs             +xim +digraphs          +modify_fname
+smartindent       +xpm +dnd               +mouse             +startuptime
+xsmp_interact -ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline
+xterm_clipboard +emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop
-xterm_save +eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax +ex_extra
-mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary +extra_search      +mouse_netterm
+tag_old_static system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc" user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc" user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc" system gvimrc
file: "$VIM/gvimrc" user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc" 2nd user gvimrc file:
"~/.vim/gvimrc" defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim" system menu file:
"$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim" fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim" f-b for
$VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/local/share/vim/vim81" Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12
-I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0
-I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2   -g -O2
-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     Linking: gcc   -L.
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic
-Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim
-lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
-lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig
-lfreetype -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl
-lselinux  -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.1 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong
-L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm
-lpthread -lcrypt  -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnuconfig
-lpython3.5m  -lruby-2.3 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

I have this file in my folder:
https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/master/jinja2/_identifier.py

Now I try to use `ctrlp`, `ctrlp-py-matcher` to navigate tags. I use `ctags` to generate the tags files.

However, I found that even though the correct tags were being generated, `:CtrlPTags` wasn't showing any tags.

I have traced it down to the file above
https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/master/jinja2/_identifier.py

which contains BOM UTF-8 header, `vim.eval` in the `ctrlp-py-matcher` fails.
`vim.eval('a:items')`:
https://github.com/FelikZ/ctrlp-py-matcher/blob/cf63fd546f1e80dd4db3db96afbeaad301d21f13/autoload/pymatcher.py#L7

Other people such as @ludovicchabant also found a similar problem and had to
work around it as shown in his fork of the `ctrlp-py-matcher` repo, and also
post process the tags file(https://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2017/02/25/aaa-gamedev-with-vim/) :

https://github.com/ludovicchabant/ctrlp-py-matcher/blob/2f6947480203b734b069e5d9f69ba440db6b4698/autoload/pymatcher.py#L22

Further, I have verfied that I if I do remove the `BOM` headers using the
following commands: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381263/242983
from the file, `:CtrlPTag` works fine again.

Currently, I basically excluded the entire `python` env folder to prevent these
issues. I can ofcourse, do some post-processing of `tags` file after `ctags`
generates the tags file and remove the BOM header, but it seems a bit hacky.

The best way would be if `vim.eval('a:items')` doesn't error out, even if its
argument contains `BOM` headers, or if there exists another function other than
`vim.eval` which won't crash when the string it contains has `BOM` headers.

Is there another way or another function other than `vim.eval` which can take
in strings which contain `BOM` headers` and not error out?

Is this by design, or a bug?

Comment: Relevant Vim ticket: [#3213](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3213)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt.. thanks.. yeah.. I created that..